# How to decrypt LockBit encrypted files

Tags: malware, windows, attacks, virus, ransomware

I've got an emergency on my PC. I remotely connected to it using Remote Desktop Connection a couple of days ago and I worked on my PC for a while and logged off. Later, when I went to log back on, I discovered there was a virus and all my files were encrypted. I discovered it was LockBit 3.0 and saw this post: [LockBit 3.0 Ransomware Unlocked](https://blogs.vmware.com/security/2022/10/lockbit-3-0-also-known-as-lockbit-black.html). It showed that the LockBit build was leaked. I downloaded the LockBit builder files and ran the builder. **Once, I ran the builder, the decryptor was inside as LB3Decryptor.exe**. I have my decryption ID and now I have the decryptor. Is there some way I can decrypt my files?

I uploaded the builder files here if anyone wants to mess with it: [LockBit builder files](https://github.com/Tennessene/LockBit). You have to run the build.bat and then **everything will be inside the "Build" directory**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not the decryptor, but a builder. It will not be used to decrypt the files already encrypted, because it don't look like there's a master key or private key on it. If you look at the `config.json` file on that repository, you will see a blank key.

The leaked files are helpful for decoding the logic of the ransomware, but if you don't have the keys, you don't have any way to decrypt the data.

Comment: Take a look at my post again. I guess I didn't make it clear the first time. I have the decryptor. But, you're saying I can't decrypt without the private key

Comment: Yes. You will build both the encryptor and the decryptor, but without the key you cannot decrypt anything.